# How can I transform Thiamine sulfate to Thiamine hydrochloride?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ionic-compounds, salt

I have got thiamine sulfate and want to have thiamine hydro chloride. Can I obtain it by dissolving thiamine sulfate in water and adding calcium chloride water solution as long as calcium sulfate will percipitate out. After it filter the solution and boil off the water? If it's not a good method, can someone tell me a better one?

Comment: If you have ion exchange resin, that’s an easier method. Also would recommend boiling off the water under reduced pressure (eg rotavap)

Comment: Calcium sulfate is relatively soluble in water. If you want a pure sample of thiamine chloride, it is better to replace calcium chloride $\ce{CaCl2}$ by barium chloride $\ce{BaCl2}$, because it produces barium sulfate which is much more insoluble than calcium sulfate. After filtration, you obtain a pure solution of thiamine chloride (Vitamin B1). But be cautious ! Barium compounds are toxic.